# problem with rig

Tags: rigging, armature

Sorry if its a simple problem this is my first time trying to rig something. The problem is when ever I move the leg different parts dont move at the same time or are distanced from one another, look at the two images below for examples of what I mean.

This is it without moving anything
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, how did you parent? maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @moonboots just put it up and I parented it by - armature deform and empty groups https://pasteall.org/blend/4e3fc1d137d243d7910d34d85b9394f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Chris' answer, instead of parenting with vertex groups, as your robot is made of separate parts, you could have parented each part to each bone: Select an object, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bone to which it is supposed to be parented to, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have to check your weight painting. Each part of your cute robot should only be parented to one bone, not to more.

[image]

as you can see in my gif, you parented that part to upperleg_l and lowerleg_l. But of course it should only be parented to lowerleg.

I just checked that one. You should also check your other parts and weight paintings.